# Crash on new activity

Tags: android, crash, forceclose

I have a problem with my app. When starting a the "FusRoDAHnomusic" activity, it crashes. I just get a force close?

### FusRoDAHActivity:

```
package com.frede.fusrodah;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.pm.ActivityInfo;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.Window;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.RelativeLayout;
import com.google.ads.AdRequest;
import com.google.ads.AdSize;
import com.google.ads.AdView;

public class FusRoDAHActivity extends Activity {
    private AdView adView2;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);
        Button next = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
        next.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Intent myIntent = new Intent(view.getContext(), FusRoDAH.class);
                startActivityForResult(myIntent, 0);
            }
        });

        Button next2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button4);
        next2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Intent myIntent = new Intent(view.getContext(), FusRoDAHnomusic.class);
                startActivityForResult(myIntent, 0);
            }
        });

        // Create an ad.
        adView2 = new AdView(this, AdSize.BANNER, "XXXXXXXXXXXX");

        // Add the AdView to the view hierarchy. The view will have no size
        // until the ad is loaded.
        RelativeLayout layout = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.main1);
        layout.addView(adView2);

        // Create an ad request. Check logcat output for the hashed device ID to
        // get test ads on a physical device.
        AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest();

        // Start loading the ad in the background.
        adView2.loadAd(adRequest);
    }

    /** Called before the activity is destroyed. */
    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        // Destroy the AdView.
        if (adView2 != null) {
            adView2.destroy();
        }
        super.onDestroy();
    }
}
```

### FusRoDAHnomusic:

```
package com.frede.fusrodah;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.pm.ActivityInfo;
import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.Window;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.RelativeLayout;
import com.google.ads.AdRequest;
import com.google.ads.AdSize;
import com.google.ads.AdView;

public class FusRoDAHnomusic extends Activity {
    private AdView adView3;
    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        return;
    }

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        setContentView(R.layout.fusrodahnomusic);
        setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);

        final MediaPlayer mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(getBaseContext(), R.raw.fusrodahnomusic);
        mediaPlayer.start(); // no need to call prepare(); create() does that for you

        Button next = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button3);
        next.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View view) {
                mediaPlayer.stop();
                Intent intent = new Intent();
                setResult(RESULT_OK, intent);
                finish();
            }
        });

        // Create an ad.
        adView3 = new AdView(this, AdSize.BANNER, "XXXXXXXXXX");

        // Add the AdView to the view hierarchy. The view will have no size
        // until the ad is loaded.
        RelativeLayout layout = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.main1);
        layout.addView(adView3);

        // Create an ad request. Check logcat output for the hashed device ID to
        // get test ads on a physical device.
        AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest();

        // Start loading the ad in the background.
        adView3.loadAd(adRequest);
    }

    /** Called before the activity is destroyed. */
    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        // Destroy the AdView.
            if (adView3 != null) {
                adView3.destroy();
            }

            super.onDestroy();
        }
    }
}
```

### FusRoDAH:

```
package com.frede.fusrodah;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.pm.ActivityInfo;
import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.Window;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.RelativeLayout;
import com.google.ads.AdRequest;
import com.google.ads.AdSize;
import com.google.ads.AdView;

public class FusRoDAH extends Activity {
    private AdView adView;

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        return;
    }

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        setContentView(R.layout.fusrodah);
        setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);
        final MediaPlayer mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(getBaseContext(), R.raw.fusrodah);
        mediaPlayer.start(); // no need to call prepare(); create() does that for you
        Button next = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);
        next.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View view) {
                mediaPlayer.stop();
                Intent intent = new Intent();
                setResult(RESULT_OK, intent);
                finish();
            }
        });

        // Create an ad.
        adView = new AdView(this, AdSize.BANNER, "XXXXXXXXXXXX");

        // Add the AdView to the view hierarchy. The view will have no size
        // until the ad is loaded.
        RelativeLayout layout = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.fusrodah);
        layout.addView(adView);

        // Create an ad request. Check logcat output for the hashed device ID to
        // get test ads on a physical device.
        AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest();

        // Start loading the ad in the background.
        adView.loadAd(adRequest);
    }

    /** Called before the activity is destroyed. */
    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        // Destroy the AdView.
        if (adView != null) {
            adView.destroy();
        }
        super.onDestroy();
    };
}
```

LogCat:

```
03-31 22:06:05.485: D/webviewglue(797): nativeDestroy view: 0x3ab4f0
03-31 22:06:05.494: D/webviewglue(797): nativeDestroy view: 0x3ab3b8
03-31 22:06:05.505: D/dalvikvm(797): GC freed 393 objects / 17312 bytes in 267ms
03-31 22:06:05.514: E/webcoreglue(797): The real object has been deleted
03-31 22:06:05.544: E/webcoreglue(797): The real object has been deleted
03-31 22:06:07.394: W/MediaPlayer(797): info/warning (1, 44)
03-31 22:06:08.234: D/AndroidRuntime(797): Shutting down VM
03-31 22:06:08.254: W/dalvikvm(797): threadid=3: thread exiting with uncaught exception     (group=0x4001b188)
03-31 22:06:08.274: E/AndroidRuntime(797): Uncaught handler: thread main exiting due to uncaught exception
03-31 22:06:08.345: E/AndroidRuntime(797): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start         activity ComponentInfo{com.frede.fusrodah/com.frede.fusrodah.FusRoDAHnomusic}:     java.lang.NullPointerException
03-31 22:06:08.345: E/AndroidRuntime(797):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2496)
03-31 22:06:08.345: E/AndroidRuntime(797):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2512)
03-31 22:06:08.345: E/AndroidRuntime(797):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2200(ActivityThread.java:119)
03-31 22:06:08.345: E/AndroidRuntime(797):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1863)
03-31 22:06:08.345: E/AndroidRuntime(797):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
03-31 22:06:08.345: E/AndroidRuntime(797):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
03-31 22:06:08.345: E/AndroidRuntime(797):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4363)
03-31 22:06:08.345: E/AndroidRuntime(797):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
03-31 22:06:08.345: E/AndroidRuntime(797):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
03-31 22:06:08.345: E/AndroidRuntime(797):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:860)
03-31 22:06:08.345: E/AndroidRuntime(797):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:618)
03-31 22:06:08.345: E/AndroidRuntime(797):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
03-31 22:06:08.345: E/AndroidRuntime(797): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
03-31 22:06:08.345: E/AndroidRuntime(797):  at                 com.frede.fusrodah.FusRoDAHnomusic.onCreate(FusRoDAHnomusic.java:66)
03-31 22:06:08.345: E/AndroidRuntime(797):  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
03-31 22:06:08.345: E/AndroidRuntime(797):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2459)
03-31 22:06:08.345: E/AndroidRuntime(797):  ... 11 more
03-31 22:06:08.475: I/dalvikvm(797): threadid=7: reacting to signal 3
03-31 22:06:08.704: I/dalvikvm(797): Wrote stack trace to '/data/anr/traces.txt'
03-31 22:06:54.401: I/Process(797): Sending signal. PID: 797 SIG: 9
```

Comment: What is your LogCat tells you. Write your complete StackTrace here, so we can get better idea about it.

Comment: Did you add the new activity to your manifest? Gets me every time.

Comment: Write your complete LogCat StackTrace here

Comment: Updated first post with logcat error.

Comment: Please do not use pastebin for your question. Questions that rely on external sites to be useful become completely useless when the link stops working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just read your stack trace. It says `NullPointerException` at line 66. 65-66 is this:

```
RelativeLayout layout = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.main1);
layout.addView(adView3);
```

So that means `layout` is `null` which means that probably `main1` is not in that layout.

Comment: How couldn't i see that. Thanks!